# Export python dataframe into tree structure in google sheets

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, google-sheets, tree

I have this dataframe:

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
1|  A   | auto | big   | red
2|  A   | moto | big   | red
3|  B   | auto | small | blue
4|  C   | auto | small | green
5|  C   | auto | big   | red
6|  C   | moto | small | blue
7|  C   | moto | small | black
```

I would like to export in Google Sheets in this form:

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3    Col4
 1|  A   |      |       |
 2|  A   | auto |       |
 3|  A   | auto | big   |
 4|  A   | auto | big   | red
 5|  A   | moto |       |
 6|  A   | moto | big   |
 7|  A   | moto | big   | red
 8|  B   |      |       |
 9|  B   | auto |       |
10|  B   | auto | small |
11|  B   | auto | small | blue
12|  C   |      |       |
13|  C   | auto |       |
14|  C   | auto | small |
15|  C   | auto | small | green
16|  C   | auto | big   |
17|  C   | auto | big   | red
18|  C   | moto |       |
19|  C   | moto | small |
20|  C   | moto | small | blue
21|  C   | moto | small | black
```

I have tried turning the Dataframe into a dictionary, but then i got stuck how to 'print' it.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

def get_tree( data ):

    df = data.filter( [ 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4' ], axis='columns' )

    d = defaultdict( lambda: defaultdict(list) )

    for row in df.itertuples():
        d[ row[1] ][ row[2] ][ row[3] ].append( row[4] )
        
    return d
```

Any hints?

Comment: pleae add your code

Comment: @raidenace check it out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DataFrame `df` like

```
  Col1  Col2   Col3   Col4
0    A  auto    big    red
1    A  moto    big    red
2    B  auto  small   blue
3    C  auto  small  green
4    C  auto    big    red
5    C  moto  small   blue
6    C  moto  small  black
```

this

```
length = df.shape[1]
data = {col: [] for col in df.columns}
old_row = tuple('' for _ in range(length))
for row in zip(*[df[col] for col in df.columns]):
    depth = max([i for i in range(length)
                 if all(old_row[j] == row[j] for j in range(i + 1))]
                + [-1])
    for n in range(depth + 1, length):
        for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
            data[col].append(row[i] if i <= n else '')
    old_row = row

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

gives you the following DataFrame (and corresponding dictionary `data`)

```
   Col1  Col2   Col3   Col4
0     A                    
1     A  auto              
2     A  auto    big       
3     A  auto    big    red
4     A  moto              
5     A  moto    big       
6     A  moto    big    red
7     B                    
8     B  auto              
9     B  auto  small       
10    B  auto  small   blue
11    C                    
12    C  auto              
13    C  auto  small       
14    C  auto  small  green
15    C  auto    big       
16    C  auto    big    red
17    C  moto              
18    C  moto  small       
19    C  moto  small   blue
20    C  moto  small  black
```

Is that what you are looking for?